# Google PubSub to Kafka Source connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, google-cloud-pubsub

I have 1 pub/sub topic & 1 Subscription in it. I was exploring [GCP PubSub Kafka Connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/pubsub/tree/master/kafka-connector).

There are 2 instances of Kafka running in 2 regions. Is it possible to use Kafka connector in both the regions, sourcing msgs from the same common subscription in Pub/Sub?

I want to figure out a way to move msgs from pub/sub to multiple kafka instances. (say round robin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want both Kafka instances to receive all of the messages, then you will need to create a second subscription on the topic. If you want each Kafka instance to receive a subset of the messages, then you can set up the two CPS Kafka source connector instances with the same subscription.

Comment: Thanks @kamal. I was also thinking on same line, ie have 2 CPS Kafka source connector, as i dont want same msg to be processed in multiple regions. However i cant figure out how to define split of msgs. say wanting 80% msgs to Region 1 & 20% to Region 2.

Comment: There isn't a way to specify what the split is across the two instances. If the two instances have roughly the same capacity, then the split should be approximately equal between them.